# angularjs + angular-snap.js : content doesn't scroll independently

Tags: html, angularjs

i have an angularJS app. i want to implement a slide menu (like facebook), i added angular-snap.js following the steps here: https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js ...this works fine in browsers.....but when i test it on an android phone, the content portion doesn't scroll.....
P.S: i tried the CSS fix given here, but no luck: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer here ..............
https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js/issues/38#issuecomment-31734154

the drawer scrolls fine by default...we just need to make a css class for the content to scroll independently:

```
.scrollable{
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
    transition-property: top, bottom;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

and add this class to the CONTENT part:

```
<div id="content" class="scrollable" snap-content snap-options="snapOpts">
```